# Stored Procedure fails, Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I really don't have that much knowledge of SP or TSQL to figure this issue out and was hoping that someone here might assist. We've got a stored procedure that gets some statistics with some inserts etc but it fails because of "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint". This is the SP:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CalculateKPIs]
AS

  DECLARE @MaxRequests DECIMAL(19,2),
          @RequestDateTime DATETIME,
          @MaxRequestsBySecond CURSOR,
          @MaxRequestsByMinute CURSOR,
          @MaxRequestsByHour CURSOR,
          @MaxRequestsByDay CURSOR;

  -- Max requests per second
    SET @MaxRequestsBySecond = CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
          SELECT TOP 1 SUM(request_count) AS requests, request_datetime
          FROM api_traffic_summary, api_kpi_value
          WHERE request_datetime > kpi_date AND kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Second'
          GROUP BY request_datetime
          HAVING SUM(request_count) > (SELECT kpi_value FROM api_kpi_value WHERE kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Second')
          ORDER BY 1 DESC;

  -- Max requests per minute
    SET @MaxRequestsByMinute = CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
          SELECT TOP 1 SUM(request_count) AS requests, CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), request_datetime, 20)
          FROM api_traffic_summary, api_kpi_value
          WHERE request_datetime > kpi_date AND kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Minute'
          GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), request_datetime, 20)
          HAVING SUM(request_count) > (SELECT kpi_value FROM api_kpi_value WHERE kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Minute')
          ORDER BY 1 DESC;

  -- Max requests per hour
    SET @MaxRequestsByHour = CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
          SELECT TOP 1 SUM(request_count) AS requests, CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), request_datetime, 20) + ':00'
          FROM api_traffic_summary, api_kpi_value
          WHERE request_datetime > kpi_date AND kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Hour'
          GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), request_datetime, 20)
          HAVING SUM(request_count) > (SELECT kpi_value FROM api_kpi_value WHERE kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Hour')
          ORDER BY 1 DESC;

  -- Max requests per day
    SET @MaxRequestsByDay = CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR
          SELECT TOP 1 SUM(request_count) AS requests, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20) + ' 00:00:00'
          FROM api_traffic_summary, api_kpi_value
          WHERE request_datetime > kpi_date AND kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Day'
          GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), request_datetime, 20)
          HAVING SUM(request_count) > (SELECT kpi_value FROM api_kpi_value WHERE kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Day')
          ORDER BY 1 DESC;

  -- Get the number of developers
  INSERT INTO api_kpi_value 
  SELECT 'Usage', 'Developers', COUNT(1), 'Now', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE()), 20) + ' 00:00:00'
  FROM api_subscriber_view;

  -- Get the number of all applications
  INSERT INTO api_kpi_value
  SELECT 'Usage', 'Applications', COUNT(1), 'All', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE()), 20) + ' 00:00:00'
  FROM api_application_view;

  -- Get the number of active applications
  INSERT INTO api_kpi_value
  SELECT 'Usage', 'Applications', COUNT(DISTINCT application_name), 'Active', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE()), 20) + ' 00:00:00' 
  FROM api_traffic_summary 
  WHERE request_datetime BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE()), 20) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 20);

  -- Get the number of API's 
  INSERT INTO api_kpi_value
  SELECT 'Usage', 'APIs', COUNT(1), 'Now', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE()), 20) + ' 00:00:00'
  FROM api_view;

  -- Get subscribers by API
  INSERT INTO api_kpi_value
  SELECT 'Subscribers', api_name + ':' + api_version, COUNT(1), 'Now', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE()), 20) + ' 00:00:00'
  FROM api_subscription_view
  GROUP BY api_name, api_version;

  -- Update max requests per second
  OPEN @MaxRequestsBySecond;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @MaxRequestsBySecond
  INTO @MaxRequests, @RequestDateTime;

  IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    UPDATE api_kpi_value
    SET kpi_value = @MaxRequests, kpi_date = @RequestDateTime
    WHERE kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Second';

  CLOSE @MaxRequestsBySecond;
  DEALLOCATE @MaxRequestsBySecond;

  -- Update max requests per minute
  OPEN @MaxRequestsByMinute;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @MaxRequestsByMinute
  INTO @MaxRequests, @RequestDateTime;

  IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    UPDATE api_kpi_value
    SET kpi_value = @MaxRequests, kpi_date = @RequestDateTime
    WHERE kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Minute';

  CLOSE @MaxRequestsByMinute;
  DEALLOCATE @MaxRequestsByMinute;

  -- Update max requests per hour
  OPEN @MaxRequestsByHour;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @MaxRequestsByHour
  INTO @MaxRequests, @RequestDateTime;

  IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    UPDATE api_kpi_value
    SET kpi_value = @MaxRequests, kpi_date = @RequestDateTime
    WHERE kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Hour';

  CLOSE @MaxRequestsByHour;
  DEALLOCATE @MaxRequestsByHour;

  -- Update max requests per day
  OPEN @MaxRequestsByDay;
  FETCH NEXT FROM @MaxRequestsByDay
  INTO @MaxRequests, @RequestDateTime;

  IF @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    UPDATE api_kpi_value
    SET kpi_value = @MaxRequests, kpi_date = @RequestDateTime
    WHERE kpi_group = 'Requests' AND kpi_name  = 'Max' AND kpi_period =  'Day';

  CLOSE @MaxRequestsByDay;
  DEALLOCATE @MaxRequestsByDay;
```

The error I receive is:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__API_KPI___348637B32645B050'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.API_KPI_VALUE'. 
The duplicate key value is (Usage, Developers, Now, Nov 20 2019 12:00AM). [SQLSTATE 23000] (Error 2627)  The statement has been terminated. [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 3621).  
NOTE: The step was retried the requested number of times (1) without succeeding.  The step failed.
```

I know that the error message specifies exactly where the issue is but I don't really understand why it keeps failing. This database is located on a SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is me being an idiot. This job actually runs fine but the problem was it was doing a "retry" if the job failed and the second time it tried to run it showed this error message since it already ran one time. The first error message was "Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation" which I just added ansi_warnings off so now the job should run fine. Thanks for helping @dataconsumer

Answer (score 0):

Please could you share the table definition of api_kpi_value ? As per your error, the primary key is duplicated and hence it fails.

You can try running these 2 statements separately and check which Insert is failing.

```
 -- Get the number of developers
  INSERT INTO api_kpi_value 
  SELECT 'Usage', 'Developers', COUNT(1), 'Now', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE()), 20) + ' 00:00:00'
  FROM api_subscriber_view;


  -- Get the number of API's 
  INSERT INTO api_kpi_value
  SELECT 'Usage', 'APIs', COUNT(1), 'Now', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE()), 20) + ' 00:00:00'
  FROM api_view;
```

Comment: SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[API_KPI_VALUE](
 [kpi_group] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
 [kpi_name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 [kpi_value] [decimal](19, 2) NOT NULL,
 [kpi_period] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
 [kpi_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [kpi_group] ASC,
 [kpi_name] ASC,
 [kpi_period] ASC,
 [kpi_date] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
I actually get the same error on both statement

Comment: OK, so the combination of primary key values  - PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [kpi_group] ASC, [kpi_name] ASC, [kpi_period] ASC, [kpi_date] ASC ) is duplicated. The duplicate key value is (Usage, Developers, Now, Nov 20 2019 12:00AM). if you need timestamp you can replace your select within insert with select 'Usage', 'Developers', COUNT(1), 'Now', CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(DAY,-1, GETDATE()), 9)